# Proof of a factorial question

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose that $n=m_1+m_2+...+m_k$ where $m_i$ are positive integers for $1 \leq i \leq k$. We want to prove that $(m_1 !)(m_2 !)\cdots (m_k!)$ divides $n!$ using group theory. My idea is that we can view $n!$ as the order of symmetric gorup $S_n$, where $(m_i !)$ as order of $S_{m_i}$, but I am stuck on how to combine them to get $(m_1 !)\cdots (m_k !)$.

Comment: Can you find a subgroup of $S_n$ isomorphic to $S_{m_1}\times S_{m_2} \times \cdots \times S_{m_k}?$

Comment: Consider the role of $S_n$ in Cayley's theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the subgroup of $S_n$ consisting of the permutations that fix each of
the subsets $\{1,2,\ldots,m_1\}$, $\{m_1+1,m_1+2,\ldots,m_1+m_2\},\ldots,
\{m_1+\cdots+m_{k-1}+1,m_1+\cdots+m_{k-1}+2,\ldots,m_1+\cdots+m_{k-1}+m_k\}$.
This has $m_1!m_2!\cdots m_k!$ elements.

Answer (score 0):

There are $n$ elements in $S_n$.  Each set of $m_i$ elements generates a subgroup, the permutations that permute those $m_i$ elements and leave all the other ones fixed.  There is a subgroup where each element stays in its set of $m_i$